# How can I set a MonoGame window's position?

Tags: monogame

How do I set the position of my window in MonoGame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `GameWindow` object's `Position` property.

Note the, [per the source as of this writing](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/GameWindow.cs), that property only exists for Windows projects using DirectX as a back-end.